# When im trying to run my login_form its show following error “undefined method `login_tables_path' for #<#<Class:0x4032300>:0x43d1e28>”

Tags: ruby-on-rails

class LoginController < ApplicationController

```
def new
    @login= Login.new;
end

    def index
        @login= Login.all;
    end

def create
        @login = Login.new(params.require(:login).permit(:username)) 
        if @login.save
        redirect_to Login_path  
    end
end
```

end

It shows that I did not set path for login_table but I did. There is login_form controller file and index.html.erb file which contain login_table coding.

The form:

```
   <h1>Log In</h1>
   <hr>
   <%= form_for(@login url:login_path) do |f| -%>
   Username:<%= f.text_field :username %></br></br>
   Password:<%= f.password_field :password %> </br></br>

   <%= f.submit "Log-in", class: "btn-submit"%>
   <%end%>
```

Comment: Please show your `routes.rb` file.

Comment: Rails.application.routes.draw do
resources :login_form
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

end

Comment: This is exactly the same question as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46129767/when-im-trying-to-run-my-login-form-its-show-following-error-undefined-method.

Answer (score 0):

*Note: This is an answer to the original version of the question that had been posted before model and controller names changing.*

You use `form_for` tag without explicit url setting. So, according to the [docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#relying-on-record-identification), Rails adjusts url-helper according to model (`LoginTable`) class name. That's why you are getting an exception with the message that `login_tables_path` is missing.

If you have a `LoginFormController`, which is not `LoginTablesController`, you should use `form_tag` with explicitly set url.

BTW, your controller should be called `LoginFormsController` by convention, and you should have:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :login_forms, only: [:index, :new, :create]
end
```

in your `routes.rb`.

After that you can check route prefix by executing `bin/rake routes` in your project directory and override your form definition with correct helper:

```
form_for(@login_table, url: helper_name_here)
```

Helper name is ***prefix***_path. So, for example, if route prefix is `login_forms`, helper name to use will be `login_forms_path`.

Also you will probably get an exception here:

```
redirect_to LoginTable_path
```

Because here you should also use a helper that will return an index action url, like this:

```
redirect_to login_forms_path
```

Comment: i have recreated the files with single name login.

Comment: while routing the file we have to provide the name of controller or model in resources?

Comment: @Shabbir Could you please rephrase your question? It's not clear what you are asking.

Comment: I am asking in routes.rb file we have to provide controller name or model name i.e table name?

Comment: @Shabbir Controller name. For example we have `UsersController`, so in `routes.rb` we should have `resources :users`. Take a look at [this guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

Answer (score 0):

First thing that you should know before using Ruby on Rails is that it works on Convention over Configuration, so writing a code without proper convention will require manual configuration and as folk says Rails Magic will not work.

**Please share your associated model, migrations and routes file for proper solution**

Few steps:

```
class LoginFormController < ApplicationController

  def new

    @login_table= LoginForm.new

  end


  def index

    @login_table= LoginForm.all

  end

  def create

    @login_table = LoginForm.new(params.require(:login_table).permit(:username)) 
    if @login_table.save
      redirect_to LoginForm_path
    end
  end
end
```

But I must tell you, you are writing code in a wrong way.
Rails convention does not support this type of coding.

Better option will be to recreate all the files and controller naming should be a single word say **LoginController** (longer names creates problem in scalability)

Comment: yeah i have recreated all files with single name login